# Good practice working with multi language content

Tags: ios, iphone, backend, multilingual

I'm working on an application which have to support the multi language.
It's A problem with the web team which implement the back-end.

After user select the application language I proposed to add a parameter related to the selected (en, it,es ...) language and the content received from the server and displayed in the application be in the selected language.

Web team propose to keep the content in english and after I process the content, to call a new transaction which provide me the content in all supported languages in application and after when I need to display something I have to identify the default content from english to selected language and display it.
I tried to find something on apple platform related to good practice related to this situation.

Which is the best approach ?
I'll continue to find references for the good approach.
Thanks for your help .

Comment: your proposal is the standard approach, but it isn't an Apple standard, it's just a common approach that people take...

Comment: Though there's no "Apple standard" for doing web based translations, I'd say the correct approach depends on the amount of translations needed (i.e. server sends just some identifier for a small set of sentences vs. real "bloat" content like text stories), and what processing you have to do with it. Translating "processed" things seems rather difficult. Translating with no context is hard to get acceptably right. Relying on certain concrete English sentences from the server to translate them in the app to translate them seems dangerous. Also, you typically want to limit the round trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...to call a new transaction which provide me the content in all
>   supported languages in application...

So, there will be 2 transactions and the second one will get you all localized strings for needed content? That means more data to transfer to mobile app, which is always bad. Store all static data in app itself and try to avoid extra data transfer to improve user experience. That is good for Apple guidelines. You approach is pretty good, but you should localize all static text in application and re-send only dynamic data.